# CSS Selectos witch Classes and HTML Elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add CSS for an option Element in a select Element that is a Class. But I in a certain way, because of my code. I wanna use Selectors to edit the CSS of the first option Element.

Imagine my code would look like this:

```
`<div class ="one">
<select name="red-dropdown">
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>

<div/>`
```

And I want to add CSS through such a similiar way

```
`Class one -> In select -> first option element {
//CSS
}`
```

How can I achieve this, I thought about something in that direction:
.one select option:first-child

As I said such things:

.one select option:first-child
`

Comment: That's exactly how you'd do it e.g. `.one select option:first-child { font-weight: bold; }` would make the first select item bold. Note you're missing a closing select tag.

Comment: You might like to make your code into a runnable snippet so we can help in more depth. For example your closing div tag is incorrect. Also select and its options are 'notoriously' [MDN's word] difficult to style so it will depend on what effect(s) you want to achieve as to how you can implement things - you could read more on this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#styling_with_css

Comment: Thanks, that answer was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this ruleset:

```css
.one > select > option:first-child {

  /* CSS declarations */

}
```